# create Amazon CloudFront streaming distribution

Tags: c#, amazon-cloudfront

I am creating an Amazon CloudFront streaming distribution using C#. When I provide my bucket name in s3origin, I get the error "Only Amazon S3 V2 style buckets are acceptable as Origin values". Here is my code:

```
CreateStreamingDistributionRequest objRequest = new CreateStreamingDistributionRequest();

objRequest.StreamingDistributionConfig.CallerReference = DateTime.Now.ToString(("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff"));
objRequest.StreamingDistributionConfig.Comment = "my First Clund front";
objRequest.StreamingDistributionConfig.Enabled = true;
objRequest.StreamingDistributionConfig.S3Origin = new S3Origin("XXXXXX.s3.amazonaws.com",originAccessIdentity);

CreateStreamingDistributionResponse objCFResponse = client.CreateStreamingDistribution(objRequest);
```

Can anybody help me create a `StreamingDistribution`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your bucket name should adhere to DNS naming standards. Check out Amazon documentation

> To conform with DNS requirements, we recommend following these
>   additional guidelines when creating buckets:
>
> Bucket names should not contain underscores (_)
>
> Bucket names should be between 3 and 63 characters long
>
> Bucket names should not end with a dash
>
> Bucket names cannot contain two, adjacent periods
>
> Bucket names cannot contain dashes next to periods (e.g.,
>   "my-.bucket.com" and "my.-bucket" are invalid)

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?BucketRestrictions.html

Comment: Thanks cloudberryman but my bucket name fullfill all the requirments but still it is throwin following error.                      "Only Amazon S3 V2 style buckets are acceptable as Origin values".